# How to exclude a specific buffer from the BufEnter autocmd group?

Tags: neovim, autocmd, buffers, lua

I want to load a plugin when I enter a buffer, so I set this event to `BufEnter`. But when I start neovim, the plugin loads at the dashboard buffer. I want to exclude that buffer. How can I do it?

## Update

I created the augroup in the `init.lua` file before `lazy.nvim` and set the plugin event to the new augroup, but when I enter neovim, I get this error:

```
Failed to setup handlers for Comment.nvim

...hare/nvim/lazy/lazy.nvim/lua/lazy/core/handler/event.lua:68: Invalid 'event': 'BufInit'

# stacktrace:
  - init.lua:65
```

###### Note

I changed the augroup name from `NVIMCMPtGrp` to `BufInit`.

The plugin unloads when I'm on dashboard, but it doesn't load when I enter a file

Comment: Which Dashboard plugin are you using [Dashboard](https://github.com/nvimdev/dashboard-nvim), [Alpha-nvim](https://github.com/goolord/alpha-nvim), [Startify](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-startify)?

Comment: I'm using [Dashboard](https://github.com/nvimdev/dashboard-nvim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution which is to use the `BufRead` event, which doesn't affect dashboard for some reason.

```lua
return {
   "your/plugin",
   event = "BufRead",
}
```

Comment: Maybe could you elaborate a bit more. I'm not sure I understand your solution fully. Which file did you modified and how?

Comment: I modified the file of the plugin that I wanted to load as soon as I open a buffer, excluding the dashboard one, and set the event from `BufEnter` to `BufRead`. In my case, I modified more than 1 file since I needed this for more plugins, but in my original question, I used nvim-cmp as an example.
For the structure of the file you can check [lazy.nvim](https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim) which is the plugin manager I use for my config,

Answer (score 0):

I would put a condition in the `autocmd` command:

For Startify I would do:

```
augroup NVIMCMP
autocmd!
autocmd BufEnter * if &filetype!=#'startify' | MyCommand | endif
augroup END
```

For Dashboard I would do:

```
augroup NVIMCMP
autocmd!
autocmd BufEnter * if &filetype!=#'dashboard' | MyCommand | endif
augroup END
```

Or is Lua variant:

```lua
local NVIMCMPtGrp = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup('NVIMCMPtGrp ', { clear = true })
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({"BufEnter"}, {group = NVIMCMPtGrp , pattern = '*', callback = function()
  if not (vim.bo.filetype == 'dashboard') then
    -- MyCommand
  end
end
})
```

Comment: I want to exclude something from an existing augroup.     
I'm using `lazy.nvim` as a package manager and I load plugins using the `event` property to load plugins in certain events, which in this case is `BufEnter`.
My question was how can I exclude the dashboard buffer from the `BufEnter` augroup, not how to create one who excludes Dashboard.

Comment: @Nias26 you cannot exclude certain buffers from the  `BufEnter` autocommand. That's why you have to check, when the autocommand triggers if it matches your buffer that you want to exclude and skip it in that case.